# AsyncTask stopped working when android:targetSdkVersion was changed from 9 to 15

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
public void OnBtnSendClick(View v)
{
    byte[] bytes = ...;  // array is assigned here

    SendTask task = new SendTask();
    task.execute(new byte[][] {bytes});   // this line is executed
}

private class SendTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(byte[]... parameters) 
    {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "SendTask.doInBackground started");   // this line is not executed
            return "OK";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
            // ...
    }
}
```

This code worked with `android:targetSdkVersion="9"` in the manifest. I changed it to `android:targetSdkVersion="15"`, and now `SendTask.doInBackground` is not executed. In debugger I see that `task.execute` line is executed, but `doInBackground` is never called.

BTW, the program contains another `AsyncTask`, which is successfully running.

Comment: is it not the log level that is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

On API >= 11 by default only one `AsyncTask` is executed at a time.

> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

One way to overcome this issue is to create a `BaseTask` and make all your tasks extends it

```
public class BaseTask extends AsyncTask
{
    ...

    public void fireInTheHole()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            this.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        else
            this.execute();
    }

    ...
}
```

Then when you need to execute it, simply call `myTask.fireInTheHole()` instead of `myTask.execute()`

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that another AsyncTask is running? SendTask is really executed after another AsyncTask (ConnectTask), but  only after ConnectTask.onPostExecute finished.

Comment: Try to use `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);`. If it works then you have a running asynctask somewhere.

Comment: OK, I understand what happens. There is another long-running AsyncTask which is used for reading incoming messages. It prevents short tasks like SendTask to be executed. I need to replace this AsyncTask with regular Thread, to meet Android programming guidelines, and execute AsyncTasks by standard way. Thanks.